# Sending Data Binding id with tag not working

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-databinding

I'm working on an Android project where i have a list of devices that i want to display thanks to a base adapter. Each Device has a light level which I want to modify with a seek bar. 
I have tried to identify the device seek bar with a tag like this :

```
<SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:tag="@{Integer.toString(ampoule.idx)}" />
```

This is my ampoule object :

```
private String Type ;
private int LevelInt;
private String hueColor;
private String Name;
private int idx;
```

And the binding :

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="ampoule"
        type="com.example.****.***.containers.LightDevice"
        />
</data>
```

Now when i try to get the tag of my baseadapter to get the Object, I get the following error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.***.***, PID: 9057
                                                                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "binding_4"
```

And here is where i get the tag  :

```
    @Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    setDimmableLevel(seekBar.getTag().toString(),progress);
}

private void setDimmableLevel(String idx, final int progress) {
    Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
    Log.d("TAG", "valeur idx : "+idx);
    final LightDevice light = LightList.getInstance().getLight(Integer.parseInt(idx));
```

The error is that my tag value is binding_4 instead of beeing the ampoule.idx value...

Any idea of what should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please try this, i think its type casting related issue, hope that its works.

```
<SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:tag="@{String.valueof(ampoule.idx)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the binding step. After binding, your View's tag should be set properly. If you've created the binding, you may need to call `binding.executePendingBindings()` to have the tag values initialized before the next line. Otherwise, it is delayed until the next frame to allow accumulation of binding value changes before the views are updated.

For an Activity, you should inflate the layout like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreate(...);
    MyLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.my_layout);
    binding.setAmpoule(new LightDevice());
}
```

If you are inflating it from a different location, you can use the static inflaters. For example, from a Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle icicle) {
    MyLayoutBinding binding = MyLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    binding.setAmpoule(new LightDevice());
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```